# UIImage Memory Problems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, memory-management, uiimage

In my app I am returned from an API the urls of images, which I want to display in the app. This is all well and good, except I started to notice that when I am given, and load, very high-res images my app memory usage spikes 200+mb, often causing it to crash, which is unacceptable.

In one particular example, I am given an image that is of the dimensions 8100*5400 pixels. When the app loaded this image it crashed.

While I first thought the problem was a memory leak I created, but after doing some research, it seems like an unavoidable issue related to the size of the image -- since the image is 43,740,000 pixels and each pixel uses 4 bytes, the memory usage of the image will be a minimum of 174,960,000 bytes, or 174.96 megabytes.

The problem is i cannot control the size of the images sent by the api - they may be any resolution, possibly even larger. Obviously a `UIImage` will not work for my purposes.

Is there any other way I can display an image with a potentially massive resolution without causing app-crashing memory usage?

Comment: What API are you using? You can often request a smaller image but different API's have different ways of doing it. For example on imgur you append `s` to the end of the img_hash to request a smaller image. Otherwise you will just have to make artful use of the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method in your `UIAppDelegate`.

Comment: dont you want to resize the image ?

Comment: @Mr.T If his app crashes before the image finishes loading then he has no opportunity to resize it.

Comment: yeah you are right!!!

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom i already check and there is no way for this particular api. How would i use `didReceiveMemoryWarning` to help solve this issue? Just abort showing the image?

Comment: Ok I thought of one more thing you could do so I am just going to provide an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: just a note - I CAN see the size (in bytes, not pixels) of the image before I download it...maybe that can help?

Comment: Honestly I stopped writing my answer because matt has provided an excellent idea. The only potential problem would be if your image is too large for the disk, which is possible, but his idea is definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of downloading the image as data into memory, which will crash your app, download it as data to disk, which will not.

You can then use the Image I/O framework to load a smaller version of the image which won't take up so much memory.

(Note that you should never attempt to display an image larger than the actual display size that you need, since that's a massive waste of memory. So, even if you can't help downloading the large image, you can at least load and display a version that is the actual much smaller size you need.)

Comment: Ok so to download it straight to a file would I use a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` and to scale the image could I do a `CGRect rect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(image.size, imageView.bounds)` followed by an `image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: rect.size))` then `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`? --wouldn't I still need to load the image into memory before doing this? How would I do it without creating a UIImage of the original?

Comment: Or is this the method you were suggesting?`CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex`

Comment: Correct; for further discussion, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_image_file_formats

Comment: I implemented this and was able to significantly cut down on memory usage. Thanks!